# Memory leak caused by reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber

Tags: java, spring

We have an application using Spring Boot. The application exposing one Rest end point (NOT using Spring WebFlux framework). The application calls few expensive bacend APIs and Cache the responses so that in future when we need we can get the APi response from Cache. We want to call and cache each of the Backend API responses on parallel. Hence we used Spring Reactor Flux from service class.

We have one Interface and its use as Below

```
public interface CacheCreator {
void callAndCreateCache (final String arg1, final String arg2)
}


final Flux<CacheCreator> cacheCreators = Flux.fromIterable(cacheCreatorList);
final int parallelism = cacheCreatorList.size();
cacheCreatorFlux
  .parallel(parallelism)
  .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
  .subscribe(cacheCreator -> cacheCreator.callAndCreateCache(ar1, arg2));
```

**Problem :** 
Functionally this is working as expected. But when load tested this is causing memory leak. Heap dump analysis (Eclipe Memory Analyser) says

92,844 instances of "reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber", loaded by "org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0xfffffff8bac20830" occupy 148,550,400 (48.58%) bytes. 
Keywords
reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber
org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0xfffffff8bac20830

30,987 instances of "reactor.core.publisher.ParallelSource$ParallelSourceMain", loaded by "org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0xfffffff8bac20830" occupy 59,693,912 (19.52%) bytes.

Keywords
reactor.core.publisher.ParallelSource$ParallelSourceMain
org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0xfffffff8bac20830

**Spring Boot Version :** 2.0.2 RELEASE

**Webserver :** Tomcat (default with Spring Boot)

**OS : Solaris**

Is there something basic which I am missing regarding Flux implementation? Can someone suggest why these objects are staying in heap and multiple full GC not able to clear it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muQnn.gif)

Comment: Are you keeping references to your `Flux` to use the caches later? Given the use case here, I don't see any reason to use Reactor - there must be some usage other than the 5 lines shown here.